# Is it possible to save EF changes to a different SQL server (connection string)?

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4, replication

We have an ASP.NET application that will use several SQL servers with peer-to-peer transactional replication. Since the application doesn't do a lot of inserts/updates (perhaps 5% of all queries) we figured it would make sense that only one SQL server should be used for inserting/updating/deleting in order to avoid most conflict issues. All SQL servers will be used for selects in order to improve the performance.

Is it possible with EF4 to make sure that changes are only stored on the first SQL server? Overriding SaveChanges(..) and switching the connection string before saving comes as an idea but I am not sure if it is possible and if EF4 will like it.

If it is not possible then what are the best practices when using EF4 with multiple SQL servers and  peer-to-peer replication?

Comment: Update: Trying to change the connection string on the fly throws the following error so we're looking for another way - "No modifications to connection are permitted after the metadata has been registered either by opening a connection or constructing the connection with a MetadataWorkspace."

Answer (score 0):

The best and perhaps only reliable place to set the connection string is by overriding the oncontext created.

It sounds like you could use a partial class.
Here is some VB sample code that may help, I'll write it in C# if that helps

This is in a partial class named the same as your context

```
Partial Public Class YourCtxContainer
Private Sub OnContextCreated()
    ' Register the handler for the SavingChanges event. 
    AddHandler Me.SavingChanges, AddressOf context_SavingChanges
End Sub

' SavingChanges event handler. 
Private Shared Sub context_SavingChanges(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Validate the state of each entity in the context before SaveChanges can succeed. 
    For Each entry As ObjectStateEntry In DirectCast(sender, ObjectContext).ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
        If Not entry.IsRelationship Then
            'Here check if the context connectionstring is what you want and if not.
            'Create a new context for your inserts and updates and pass your entity over                
            'Then mark it handled so the current context dismisses it.

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to pass the entity changes over the new context? Is is possible to do that with multiple added, modified and probably linked to each other entities?